# Am Getting Not Acceptable error when i add img tag

Tags: wordpress

When I am trying to add img tag in my divi theme its showing "Not Acceptable  An appropriate representation of the requested resource /aca/wp-admin/post.php could not be found on this server.  Additionally, a 406 Not Acceptable error was encountered while trying to use an Error Document to handle the request." error

Comment: Please show your code and full stack trace

Answer (score 0):

How do you embed your Images? You can use the Wordpress Function:

```
get_the_post_thumbnail( 
    int|WP_Post $post = null,
    string|array $size = 'post-thumbnail', 
    string|array $attr = ''
)
```

Comment: I have added my image tag inside divi builder column